# field type mismatches in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elastic-stack

I am dumping data in to **ElasticSearch** from a json file which is exported from mongodb. I am facing an issue where my data from json with array fields converted into a string.

```
      "_source" : {
          "CITIES" : [
            "ABC"
          ],
          "CITY_AREAS" : """["COLONY (AIT)"]""",
          "INTERESTS" : [
            "CARS"
          ]}
```

I am not doing any mapping and I know the elastic is using its default mapping on the basis of very first document which got inserted in ES.

I want to find a solution where I run the update command to update the fields with array type for all the documents containing "**CITY_AREAS**"
E.G :

```
"CITY_AREAS" : ["COLONY (AIT)"]
```

P.S : Some documents are having "CITY _AREAS" key and some don;t have.

Comment: try ingest pipeline with reindex api or script with update by query api. if you are going with script then you can write painless script to convert string to array.

Comment: i don't want to do this with plan script, i am looking to do this with update script within query  thats why looking for solution here

Answer (score 0):

you will need to reindex for this, so that it uses the correct mapping type. an update will not work